# Smooth Terrain Collision - 3D

Tags: java, opengl, collision, smoothing, terrain

I would like to have smooth terrain collision in my game engine, when i say smooth I mean the player's height isn't determined by one vertex. I belive barycentric coordinates are the way to go. And I've spent a good 7 hours researching this, but none of the code I've seen actually works and it doesn't explain it in plain-english either.

This is all I have so far. :(

```
public float getHeightAt(float xPos, float zPos) {
        Vector3f one = new Vector3f((float)xPos, ((float)new Color(heightMap.getRGB((int)xPos, (int)zPos)).getRed())/255f*exaggeration*scale, (float)zPos);
        Vector3f two = new Vector3f((float)xPos+1, ((float)new Color(heightMap.getRGB((int)xPos+1, (int)zPos)).getRed())/255f*exaggeration*scale, (float)zPos);
        Vector3f three = new Vector3f((float)xPos, ((float)new Color(heightMap.getRGB((int)xPos, (int)zPos+1)).getRed())/255f*exaggeration*scale, (float)zPos+1);

        float height = mid(one, two, three, new Vector3f(xPos, 0f, zPos));
        System.out.println(height);
        return height + 0.25f;
    }

    private float mid(Vector3f a, Vector3f b, Vector3f c, Vector3f p) {
        Vector3f AB = a.mul(b);
        Vector3f BC = b.mul(c);

        Vector3f norm = AB.cross(BC);
        float n0 = norm.getX();
        float n1 = norm.getY();
        float n2 = norm.getZ();

        return (n0*a.getX() + n1*a.getY() + n2*a.getZ() - n0*p.getX() - n2*p.getZ()) / n1;
    }
```

It works but it isn't smooth and I don't even know ifit is barycentric.

Here is an example of what I want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngJ6ISfXG3I

Comment: You might want to try Bi-linear interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the smoothed height, there are two main steps:

#### I - Create a function to get the height from position

Create the function `public float getHeightAt(float xPos, float zPos)` following these instructions:

1. Check if the camera/player is inside the ground square

   ```
   if(xPos > 0 && xPos < nbVerticesX && zPos > 0 && zPos < nbVerticesZ)
   ```
2. Get the point **P** nearest **xPos** and **zPos**
3. Get the normal **N** or compute it
4. Compute constant **d** of the plane equation

   ```
   double d = -(P.x * N.x + P.y * N.y + P.z * N.z);
   ```
5. Return compute height

   ```
   return -(d + N.z * zPos + N.x * xPos)/N.y;
   ```

#### II - Compute approximate height

Use this function to get the smoothed height:

```
public float getHeightApprox(float x, float z)
{
    return ( (getHeightAt(x,z)
            + getHeightAt(x + 1, z)
            + getHeightAt(x - 1, z)
            + getHeightAt(x, z + 1)
            + getHeightAt(x, z - 1)) / 5);
}
```

Maybe you will have to adapt your code, but these pieces of code works fine for me. Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

## Position and slope

Player position can be determined by one point. The case here is to create a relatively smooth function from the distinct values on the height map.

Interpolation should do the trick. It will in the simplest case provide a slope on the whole heightmap.

## Bi-linear interpolation (quad)

At any point in time the palyer position in in some rectangle (quad) of the heightmap. We can evaluate the height in any point of this rectangle by doing bi-linear interpolation.

We do this for one axis on both edges and then on the second axis for the remaining edge.

```
^
| A--------B
| |        |
| | P      |
| |        |
| C--------D
Y 
*X------------>

// This could be different depending on how you get points
// (basically generates a [0, 1] value depending on the position in quad;
px = P.x - (int)P.x
py = P.y - (int)P.y
AB = A.h * (1.0 - px) + B.h * px;
CD = C.h * (1.0 - px) + D.h * px;
ABCD = AB * (1.0 - py) + CD * py;
```

`ABCD` is the resulting height

## Considerations

This method is not perfect and might produce visual glitches depending on how you actually draw the quad in your rendering pipeline.

Also keep in mind that this works best if quads are bigger than your actual moving actor. In case when actor simultaneously is standing on several tiles a some kind averaged method should be used.